# Is the work done zero if we have thrust?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, work, rocket-science

If we go by this formula. Work done= force x distance x cosθ. Now if thrust is  the force applied on a surface in a direction perpendicular or normal to the surface. Which means if we take thrust to be the force. So if thrust is perpendicular then θ is 90. So cos 90 is zero. Which should give the answer as work =0.

Is work zero if thrust is perpendicular to a surface.

Sorry I know this is a simple question. But I would appreciate if someone helps me clear this doubt.

Comment: I think your scenario is unclear. Please make it more clear.Assuming your scenario is one object on a surface and a force is applied on the object(no other force is acting I assume). Then, you are forgetting newton's second law. Because wherever the direction of the force is the displacement will occur in that direction too. So theta=0 degree. So W=Fs

Comment: The angle we are talking about here is not some random angle that you just happen to stumble across. $\theta$ is the angle between the direction of the force and the distance vector. We have gone over this before, haven't we? The symbols in physical equations have specific meanings, and meaning matters.

Answer (score 0):

The work done is the dot product of the force times the displacement:

$$ dW = d\mathbf F \cdot d\mathbf x = |dF|\,|dx|\,\cos\theta $$

where $\theta$ is the angle between the two vectors $d\mathbf F$ and $d\mathbf x$.

If you have a force $d\mathbf F$ normal to the surface then any displacement lying in the surface will be normal to $d\mathbf F$ and therefore the work done will be zero. A good example is an object in a circular orbit where the motion is normal to the gravitational force and consequently the work done is zero.

But this is only true for displacements lying in your surface. Suppose the surface is the bottom of a rocket with the thrust normal to it. In this case the motion of the rocket is also normal to the surface, i.e. parallel to the thrust, so the work done is not zero.

Answer (score 0):

If the thrust (or a force) causes the object to move or accelerate then the work done by that thrust or as a matter of fact, by any force in not zero.

Answer (score 0):

Work done is force times displacement of force in the direction of force.

If you apply a force at right angles to a surface and there is a displacement of the  surface in the direction of the force then the force does work.

Mathematically this is written as $W=\vec F \cdot \vec x = Fx\cos \theta$ where $W$ is the work done by a force $\vec F$ undergoing a displacement $\vec x$ where angle $\theta$ is the angle between the force and the displacement of the force **not** the angle between the force and a surface.

$x \cos \theta$ is the distance moved by the force in the same direction as the force.